# Not able to access java classes via Eclipse Plug-in

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-jdt

I am still facing problems in writing my Eclipse Java Parser project. I want to write a parser that goes over the structure of one of my workspace project and returns all variables. I tried multiple approaches, but none of it worked.

When I iterate over the `IResource` array, it recognizes all java classes and packages correctly. But when I try to access the corresponding java class, it does not work. It either does not find anything or throws an Exception.

I imported the project that I want to parse in my test workspace (that opens automatically when you run the eclipse plugin project) and I added the project as a "real" plugin to my current workspace. Error messages were the same.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong. The code is able to find all projects and `IResources` of my workspace, but I am not able to "access" the files.

Do I have an error in the conversion from `IFile` to `char[]`?

My Code so far is:

```
IWorkspaceRoot workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
IProject myProject = workspace.getProject("nameOfProject");
IResource[] members = myProject.getFolder ("/src/main/java/com/xy").members();


for (IResource member : members) {
    if (member instanceof IContainer) {
    }
    if (member instanceof IFile) {
        if (member != null) {
            if (member.getFileExtension().equals("java")) {

                //1st approach
                for (Field field : member.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
                    //does not go into here
                    System.out.println("fields" + field.getName());
                }

                //2nd approach
                ICompilationUnit cu = (ICompilationUnit) JavaCore.create(member);
                //returns name of class
                System.out.println(cu.getElementName());
                //throws exception
                System.out.println(cu.getTypes().length);

                //3rd approach
                for (TypeVariable<?> field: member.getClass().getTypeParameters()) {
                    //does not go into here
                    System.out.println(field.getName());
                }

                //4th approach
                int i=0;
                Inputstream is = ((IFile)member).getContents();
                char [] buffer = new char [is.available()];
                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))

                while ((i = r.read())!= -1) {
                    buffer[i++] = (char) i;
                }

                //throws exception Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [nameOfProject does not exist]
                ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);
                parser.setSource(buffer);
                parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
                parser.setResolveBindings(true);


                final CompilationUnit comp = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);

                comp.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean visit(VariableDeclarationFragment v) {
                        System.out.println(v.getName());
                })

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `member.getClass()` tells you about the class that implements `IFile`. It is absolutely nothing to do with the contents of the file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ok this makes sense. So my first and third approach will not work. But what about the second and forth approach? What is wrong with them? I would very much appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry but I am not an expert on these JDT APIs.

Comment: what happens when you set the source as the `ICompilationUnit` in your 4th approach, say ,`parser.setSource(cu);`

Comment: Also what had worked from previously is getting `ICompilationUnit`s from `IPackageFragment`s, like,  `IPackageFragment[] packages = JavaCore.create(project).getPackageFragments();
IPackageFragment mypackage = packages.get(0);
ICompilationUnit[] units = mypackage.getCompilationUnits();`.  Apply filtering using the package name as per you need.